# Send Apex Warning Emails with Inactive User

Tags: administration, user-management

Not a question that will necessary be of use to most people, but I recently noticed that I had an admin in an org with "Send Apex Warning Emails" on the user. That user got deactivated and I haven't been involved since, but I still get Apex warning emails whenever there is an error. I would assume that inactivating a user would turn off everything, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I haven't found any documentation stating either way, so I am curious if this is a bug or correct.

Comment: SF probably decided that it was better to inform that guy that errors were happening, expecting him/her to do something about it, instead of ignoring the errors completely if no other (active) user was receiving Apex email warnings.